# Validation value of parent in model Child, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to ask the started_on value of parent in child_model.
I want to compare, if it has the same period

assumed, I have these two classes

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
```

And this class, Child_Class:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  validates :name, presence: true, :length => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 50 }
  validates :finished_on, presence: true, date: {not_equal: :started_on}
  validates :started_on, presence: true, date: {after: :parent.started_on}
end
```

What I need is the started_on value of parent

`:parent.started_on` returns me

```
undefined method 'started_on' for :project:Symbol
```

And I'm using this validators for my date
[Validators](http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/how-to-validate-dates-in-rails-4/)
Thanks

Comment: the `:parent` is a symbol, you cannot call methods on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  validates :name, presence: true, :length => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 50 }
  validates :finished_on, presence: true, date: {not_equal: :started_on}
  validate :validate_started_on

  private

  def validate_started_on
    return if parent.nil?
    return if started_on > parent.started_on
    errors.add :started_on, :should_be_after_the_parent_started_on 
  end
end
```

Comment: comparison of Date with nil failed

Comment: `>> self
=> #<WorkPackage id: nil, name: "", started_on: "2015-11-06", finished_on: "2015-12-12", person_month: 0, parent_id: nil, project_id: 7, team_id: 1>`

Comment: `>> self.parent
=> nil`

Comment: i added a check for the parent

Comment: yes, but still not working, because I getting by self.parent just nil

Comment: eigentlich gehört jedes Arbeitspaket zu einem Projekt. D.h. Workpackge.parent muss nicht nil sein. aber ist es so. Keine Ahnung wieso

Comment: It not having a parent is an issue with your code, assign it a parent.  There isn't anything wrong with Yury's code.

Comment: Thanks @japed. But don't forget, that my code can you see up there. If you can you help me, please correct this

Comment: undefined method `to_i' for Mon, 06 Jul 2015:Date

Comment: @Arthur I fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use it without a symbol.

i.e.

```
parent.started_on
```

As outlined in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)

Comment: you mean so: `validates :started_on, presence: true, date: {after: parent.started_on}`    But so don't working

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'project_started_on' for #<Class:0x007fdb996f0438>`

Comment: What is your date validation, if you're using custom things to get help you're going to need to mention it.  I'd imagine `validates :started_on, presence: true, date: {after: Proc.new{|x| x.parent.started_on } }` but I have no idea if that'll work because I don't know what your'e using.